# Libgdx html (gwt) font error - Invalid page id

Tags: html, gwt, libgdx

When I try to run html application I get this error in browser:

```
GwtApplication: exception: Error loading font file: fonts/comic-en.fnt
Error loading font file: fonts/comic-en.fnt
Invalid page id:
For input string: ""
```

Android build runs always successfully, the font file is correct. This bug happens  even while running libgdx sample projects. Is there some secret magic?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It helps if you can post the code to show us what you think may have a problem. Otherwise all we can do is read the error message

Comment: I believe libGdx will only work with bitmap fonts in HTML. You can find a tool just for that 'Hiero' on their tools download page: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/tools.html

Comment: You can try this: 'BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont();' . The result will be the same.

Comment: Fixed in https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/4475

Comment: @OlegKilimnik You should answer your own question with that "Fixed" note/link so the answer is more evident to others looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in [github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/4475](http://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/pull/4475)